# Primefaces two dataTable update and add data from one to another

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have two dataTables in my JSF page they are placed in a dialog that pops up on some action, these dataTables has data from a list in my managed bean, what I am trying to do is when I double click on a row in my first data I want to add it to the second one and I have achieved that but it only occurs when I close the dialog and open it again, I have tried to use ajax update to update my second dataTable on the action but the issue is still occurring and my other issue that I want to HIDE the data from the first dataTable when I move it to the second one without removing it from the list or (at least dont allow the user to move the same item twice) any suggestions please? Here is my dialog and data tables:

```
<p:dialog modal="true" width="50%" height="50%" widgetVar="test"
    id="dialog">
    <p:dataTable id="tblAllQuestions" value="#{mbInstructor.fullList}"
        var="asEmp" selectionMode="single"
        selection="#{mbInstructor.currentExamQuestion}" rowKey="#{asEmp.id}"
        rowIndexVar="rowIndex">
        <p:ajax event="rowDblselect"
            update="@parent:tblAllQuestions2"
            process="@this" listener="#{mbInstructor.submitForm()}" />
        <p:column headerText="#" width="20">
                    #{rowIndex+1}
                </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="#{msg2.get('employee')}" width="200">
                    #{asEmp.questionTxt}
                </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>


    <p:dataTable id="tblAllQuestions2"
        value="#{mbInstructor.formsQuestion}" var="as" selectionMode="single"
        selection="#{mbInstructor.currentExamQuestion}" rowKey="#{as.id}"
        rowIndexVar="rowIndex">
        <p:ajax event="rowDblselect"
            update="@parent:pnlfourmData"
            process="@this" />
        <p:column headerText="#" width="20">
                    #{rowIndex+1}
                </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="#{msg2.get('employee')}" width="200">
                    #{as.question.questionTxt}
                </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>



    <h:outputText value="[no selection made]"
        rendered="#{empty mbInstructor.model.target}" />
    <p:commandButton id="formSubmit" value="Submit"
        actionListener="#{mbInstructor.submitForm()}" style="margin-top:5px" />


</p:dialog>
```

I have tried to update the whole dialog as well but it disappear when i do the action, so I added the following to my ajax to show it again

```
  oncomplete="PF('test').show()"
```

but the dialog does not show up when it finish.

Comment: put the two dataTable inside a form and update the form

Comment: @yagamiLight I have tried that but no luck